# How to make a div stick to top when it reaches the top of the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make `#headnav` stick to the top when the page's scroll position reaches the top, then unstick when it would be returned to its original position?

P.S. The repeated "CONTENT" in the code is to simulate scrolling. It is not a spam

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5z4paLgr/)

```
<h1>I AM A HEADER</h1>
<div id="headnav"></div>
<pre><h1>
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
</h1></pre>
```

```
body {
    margin:0
}

#headnav {
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Well.. you need a bit of JavaScript for it too.. any effort in this?

Comment: Really, this question is off topic, but it looked fun.  Here's my stab at it: http://jsfiddle.net/5z4paLgr/2/

Comment: I have but I have had no success whatsoever

Answer (score 3):

This is a very simple thing to do.

Find out what the original position of the header is, then attach a scroll handler to the body which checks the scroll position against the original position of the div.

- If the scroll position is greater than the original position, add `position: fixed`
- If the scroll position is less than the original position, remove `position: fixed`

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5z4paLgr/5/))

```
var headnav = document.getElementById('headnav');
var headnavPos = headnav.offsetTop;

window.onscroll = function() {
    if(document.body.scrollTop > headnavPos) {
        if(headnav.style.position !== 'fixed') {
            headnav.style.position = 'fixed';
        }
    } else  {
        if(headnav.style.position === 'fixed') {
            headnav.style.position = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give `position: fixed` to `h1`:

```
h1 {position: fixed; top: 0;}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5z4paLgr/1/**

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure that understand u correctly but may be this help you

**Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jg4kdfqs/1/**

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var HeaderTop = $('#header').offset().top;
  var hh =HeaderTop + 300;

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > HeaderTop ) {
      if($(window).scrollTop() > hh) {
        $('#header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', background:'#000'});   
      } else{
        $('#header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});  
      }


    } else {
      $('#header').css({position: 'static',background:'red'});
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
  nav
</div>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry i will do

Answer (score 0):

Similar to tarasikgoga but purely javascript:

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/5z4paLgr/3/

**Javascript**

```
var attached = false;

window.onscroll = function (e) {
    if(!attached && window.scrollY > 150){
        attached = true;
        document.getElementById("headnav").classList.add('fixed-top');
        document.getElementById("content").classList.add('content-margin-top');
    }
    if(attached && window.scrollY < 150){
        attached = false;
        document.getElementById("headnav").classList.remove('fixed-top');
        document.getElementById("content").classList.remove('content-margin-top');
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:0
}
h1{
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
}
#headnav {
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
#headnav.fixed-top{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
.content-margin-top{
    margin-top: 75px;
}
```

**HTML**
Just add id="content" to your content div

Adjust with yours heights (here you have 150px for header and 75px for menu)